# packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RTT) always returns false

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I was trying to make a flutter plugin package to learn if device has Wi-Fi RTT scan support. After I tried the code on a few physical device I got always false. Than I took a look at [supported phones](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt#supported-devices) and saw Pixel 4 is supporting this feature. And then I created an emulator which runs Pixel 4 and tried code and got `false` again.

This is kotlin side:

```
package com.example.has_wifi_rtt

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result

/** HasRttFeaturePlugin */
class HasWifiRttPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {

  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel
  private lateinit var packageManager: PackageManager

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "has_wifi_rtt")
    packageManager = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext.packageManager
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "checkRtt") {
      result.success(packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RTT))
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
}
```

This is flutter side:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HasWifiRtt {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('has_wifi_rtt');

  /// Returns a Future<bool> which indicates the device has wifi rtt or not.
  static Future<bool> checkRtt() async {
    return await _channel.invokeMethod("checkRtt");
  }
}
```

Also [the package that I wrote](https://pub.dev/packages/has_wifi_rtt)

I don't know what is wrong maybe the devices are really don't support rtt or my code is wrong.